# Running Multiple SQL Statements Stored in Temp Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to be able to grant users select access to all tables contained in a SQL view. All I want to have to do is type in the UserID and then View Name and my script will generate and run a SQL statement, granting select access for every table used by that view. I have the following:

```
declare @user varchar(40)
declare @view varchar(80)
declare @authcommand table
(authstatement varchar(max), rownum varchar(3))
set @user = 'FMPCO\dbauman'
set @view = 'pvtapvendanalysis'
CREATE TABLE #temp
(NAME VARCHAR(250), [type] VARCHAR(250), updated CHAR(2), selected CHAR(3), [column] VARCHAR(250))
INSERT #temp
EXEC sp_depends @view
insert into @authcommand
SELECT distinct concat('grant select on ', name, ' to ', @user), DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS RowNum
FROM #temp t
--select * from @authcommand
exec(@authcommand)
drop TABLE #temp
```

The commented out select statement returns pre-made "grant select" statements that I would expect from this new temporary table, in addition to each row number. Now, I would like to be able to execute each statement in that table. When I run the script, the Exec command produces the error:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@authcommand".

How can I get closer to being able to run each "grant select" statement stored in this temporary table?

Comment: Maybe try iterating through row by row?  something like `while @counter < 100 begin exec(select authstatement from @authcommand where rownum = @counter) set @counter = @counter + 1 end`

Comment: `exec(@authcommand)`? Isn't `@authcommand` a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what are you trying to do, but assuming each row has a statement to execute, something like this should do the work:

```
DECLARE @exec NVARCHAR(MAX)
WHILE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM @authcommand )
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @exec = authstatement, @rownum = rownum FROM @authcommand
    EXEC(@exec)
    DELETE FROM @authcommand WHERE rownum = @rownum
END
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. All I had to do was put brackets ([ ]) around the username that I wanted to establish the permissions for. Thank you!!!